# Remove any leading Blankspace inside an Input

Tags: php, jquery

`<input type='text'>`

for an input like this, How can i dynamically delete any whitespace leading in it for example if someone typed `'_______'` __ as spaces, it won't read and act like an empty value `''` How can i prevent that and check it in both JQuery and PHP.

I've tried

`if($_POST['input'] != ' ' && !empty($_POST['input'])){run query}`

But if i used two spaces instead of one the query will work

Comment: in js use `.trim()`

Comment: Use trim() method. Here you go with the example https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you should apply trim() and empty() function:

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['name']))){
//run 
}
```

In JQuery apply $.trim().

Comment: that actually solved the entire problem, didn't think about it at all.